# Redirect the result of execl function

Tags: c, linux, unix, execl

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        int cpid=fork();
        if(cpid==0){
                execl("/bin/ls","ls","-lah","--color",NULL);
        }
        else{
                int status;
                waitpid(cpid,&status,0);
                if(status!=0)
                        printf("Error Occured\n");
        }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 1 guest guest 4.0K Jan 12 15:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 guest guest 4.0K Jan 12 15:21 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 guest guest 7.2K Jan 12 15:19 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guest guest  372 Jan 12 15:20 execl.c
$
```

In the above program, parent create a child and the child execute the ls command. But, my requirement is to save the output of ls in an array in parent. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec*()` family functions replace the current process's *image* with new one. So you can't read it directly. You don't need a child process to read the output from an external command. You can use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to achieve that.

If you *do* have to create a child process, then you can use [`pipe(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to read from the output from the child process. You can find a simple example on the linked man page.

Comment: *"You don't need a child process to read the output from an external command."* Maybe I'm being pedantic, but what do you think `popen` does under the hood?

Comment: Perhaps, you don't need to "create one yourself" may be accurate. But I am going to feed trolls and pedants, I can be here all day. I would expect anyone to have a look at the linked manual page before using it to understand what popen does.

Answer (score 2):

To use `popen()` is one possibility, but if you want to go with `fork()/exec*()`, you would do this:

Before the `fork()`, create a pipe and attach it to stdout in the child

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
```

After the fork, in the child process close the read fd and attach the write fd to stdout:

```
close(fds[0]);
dup2(fds[1], 1);
close(fds[1]);
```

In the parent process, close the write fd and read from the read-fd to get the output:

```
close(fds[1]);
read(fds[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
```

If you need buffering, you can call `fdopen()` on the read-fd in the parent process.